# What motivates clockwork theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, fine-tuning

[Clockwork](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07962) is a new model-building gadget that produces very small couplings starting from a theory with no small numbers at all, in an attempt to solve the hierarchy problem.

To describe it as simply as possible: consider $N$ real scalar fields $\phi_i$ with potential
$$V(\phi) = \frac{m^2}{2} \sum_i (\pi_i - q \pi_{i+1})^2$$
where $q > 1$. There is a single mode that remains massless, namely the one with
$$\pi_i = \frac{\pi_0}{q^i}.$$
It may be viewed as a Goldstone mode in a simple UV completion which I omit just for brevity. Suppose we are at low energies and see only this mode. If something couples to $\pi_N$ only, then the effect of the coupling is suppressed by $q^N$ since the overlap of the Goldstone mode with $\pi_N$ is small. For order $1$ values of $q$ and $N$, $q^N$ can be very large.

Clockwork theory is extremely hot right now, with a citation occurring about once a week. However, I don't understand the key motivation behind such a potential. The result seems to depend sensitively on the particular pattern of interactions. There is no symmetry that demands the interactions only link $\pi_i$ to $\pi_{i \pm 1}$, and no reason the coefficient $q$ can't depend on $i$. I feel that we have replaced one fine-tuning with $N^2$ tunings (the $\pi_i \pi_j$ interactions), since there is nothing that fixes their values.

I've heard that such models are related to "quiver gauge theories" which are motivated by some complicated stuff in string theory, and known in phenomenology as "moose models". Can somebody explain the motivation here, in a way an ordinary physicist (me) can understand?

Comment: As far as I know, these models can arise from dimensional deconstruction of a 5D theory. This explains part of the pattern, although there's still the dependence on the profile of the metric in the extra dimension, which has to be fixed to give constant $q_i=q$ (by some other mechanism). Is this the kind of justification you're looking for?

Comment: @coconut I’ve heard of that but I’m not sure how 5D models are motivated, or this particular one.

Comment: The motivation for many 5D models (Randall-Sundrum, large extra dimensions, this one...) is in fact that they solve the hierarchy problem. The idea is that the extra dimension is too small to be measured, but it allows for some mechanism for the hierarchy to be generated.

Comment: @coconut I know that, but I still don't get how 5D models are _motivated_. Models such as Randall-Sundrum and clockwork require very specific 5D geometries, which seem to be picked solely to solve the hierarchy problem and maybe leave some collider signatures. For some reason this feels less reasonable to me than, say, specifying the SM has 3 generations because of the results of hundreds of measurements.

Comment: @coconut On the other hand, SUSY feels motivated to me even solely as a hierarchy problem fix because there is some sense of uniqueness to it, and imposing it is "just adding a symmetry". But perhaps I'm biased and these 5D models aren't actually fundamentally different, just weirder looking.

Comment: In Randall-Sundrum, the geometry is generated by some vacuum energy in the bulk and the branes. I don't know if there's something similar in the clockwork, but there might be...